# How to copy and paste data from horizontal to vertical?

Tags: vba, excel

The data in my original spreadsheet is listed horizontally.
For instance:

**A B C D E F G**

**1** A a 2 3 4 5 6

**2** B b 1 3 4 5 6

**3** C c 1 2 4 6 7

I would like to arrange this table in a vertical way. like this below:

**A B C**

**1** A a 2

**2** A a 3

**3** A a 4

**4** A a 5

**5** A a 6

**6** B b 1

**7** B b 3

.

.

.
I have figured out how to find the last row to paste the values

```
 Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1,0)
```

And I am stacked in how to do the proper loop to find each number and paste them accordingly in the vertical way, also matching with column A and B.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? The code you posted doesn't say much. And all your values are on separate columns?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Sub ArrangeVertical()

Dim MyWorkbook As Workbook
Dim Sheet1 As Worksheet
Dim Sheet2 As Worksheet

Dim myRow As Long
Dim rowPointer As Long
Dim columnPointer As Long
Dim lastColumn As Long
Dim LastRow As Long

Set MyWorkbook = Workbooks(ActiveWorkbook.Name)
Set Sheet1 = MyWorkbook.Worksheets("SaleTeam3")
Set Sheet2 = MyWorkbook.Worksheets("SaleTeam4")
myRow = 1

LastRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row

For rowPointer = 1 To LastRow
    lastColumn = Sheet1.Cells(rowPointer, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    For columnPointer = 3 To lastColumn
        Sheet2.Cells(myRow, 1).Value = Sheet1.Cells(rowPointer, 1).Value
        Sheet2.Cells(myRow, 2).Value = Sheet1.Cells(rowPointer, 2).Value
        Sheet2.Cells(myRow, 3).Value = Sheet1.Cells(rowPointer, columnPointer).Value
        myRow = myRow + 1
    Next columnPointer
Next rowPointer



End Sub
```

[image: Before]
[image: After]

Answer (score 0):

This will **scan the sheet call "Sheet1"** and **output the result in the sheet called "sheet2"**, I've *marked where to change these names* so you can decline it for your need :

```
Sub NeferZhang()

Dim Ws As Worksheet, _
    Wop As Worksheet, _
    Wrow As Integer, _
    FirstRun As Boolean

FirstRun = True
'-------Change name here-------
Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
'-------Change name here-------
Set Wop = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

Wop.Cells.ClearContents
Wop.Cells.ClearFormats

For i = 1 To Ws.Range("A" & Ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For k = 3 To Ws.Range("A" & i).End(xlToRight).Column
        Wrow = Wop.Range("A" & Wop.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        If Wrow <> 2 And Not FirstRun Then
            'Nothing to change
        Else
            'Only change at the first try, to write on first row
            Wrow = 1
            FirstRun = False
        End If
        Wop.Range("C" & Wrow + (k - 3)).Value = Ws.Cells(i, k).Value
    Next k
    'Copy A and B columns
    Wop.Range("A" & Wrow & ":B" & Wrow + (k - 4)).Value = Ws.Range(Ws.Cells(i, 1), Ws.Cells(i, 2)).Value
Next i

Set Ws = Nothing
Set Wop = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need that as a VBA code? You can simply copy your data and then paste it with right-click > Transpose. That will do the job.

In VBA something like this should work:

```
Public Sub copyTrans()
    Range("A1:G3").Copy
    Range("A4").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
End Sub
```

(Instead of `Range("A1:G3")`, you can of course use a different function to find the last cell)

**Edit:**
Sorry, i've read your question a bit too quickly. Transpose will convert this:

```
A a 2 3 4 5 6
B b 1 3 4 5 6 
C c 1 2 4 6 7
```

to this:

```
A B C
a b c
2 1 1
3 3 2
4 4 4
5 5 6
6 6 7
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub primer3()
Dim myArr1, myArr2
    myArr1 = Range("A1:C8")
    myArr2 = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(myArr1)
    Range("A11:H13") = myArr2
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**